# Firebase access parent field in CollectionGroup query where clause

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to use CollectionGroup but filter it by a field on the parent record. I am sure I read somewhere that you could use 'parent' in the file path, but I have tried the following but it doesn't work - no documents are returned. I have added a single field index.

```
const q = query(collectionGroup(db, "office"), where("parent.ownerId", "==", userId));

const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
   querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      console.log(doc.data());
   })
})
```

Comment: Firestore queries can only filter on data that is contained in the documents they return. Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75673961/query-documents-in-a-firestore-subcollection-based-on-a-field-in-the-parent-docu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to use CollectionGroup but filter it by a field on the parent record.

That's not possible.  You can only filter on fields in documents that would be matched by a query.  You can't match any parent documents or fields in any type of query. The dot notation you're using is for matching nested map fields within document fields.

Your only solution here, without reorganizing your collections altogether, is to copy the parent document fields into the documents you want to query with the collection group query.

Comment: Thanks, that was I was afraid of. I was trying to avoid copying the owner down to each record in the sub collection as if in my example the owner changes on the parent record I have to them go through records in the collection and update the owner there too. I am able to restructure the collection of there is a better way of achieving this